# How to multiprocess operations on dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I have to perform lots of operations on a dataframe and it takes a long time using a single core. I am trying to implement multiprocessing.

Right now while I am trying to figure out how it works so i am using a simpler version where i just want to add values from data

```
import multiprocessing
import pandas as pd

def add_values(a):
    df = pd.DataFrame([{'n':a}])
    return df

df = pd.DataFrame([{'n':0}])
data = [9, 4, 5]
with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4) as pool:
    df = df.add(pool.map(add_values, data))

df
```

I would like df to return a dataframe with n=18 but i get this error message ValueError: Unable to coerce to Series, length must be 1: given 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is how you treat the return value from your multiprocessing calls. `pool.map()` returns a `list`. In this particular case, it will be a list of dataframes, i.e, what your call expands to is equivalent to `df = df.add([dfn9, dfn4, dfn5])`, where the `dfnX`s are different dataframes.

This input is neither expected nor handled by `df.add()`, which expects something that can be turned into a `pd.Series` object and added to the original frame. Instead, you need to take this list and "manually" reduce it, e.g. as:

```
import multiprocessing
import pandas as pd

def add_values(a):
    df = pd.DataFrame([{'n':a}])
    return df

df = pd.DataFrame([{'n':0}])
data = [9, 4, 5]
with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4) as pool:
    #df = df.add(pool.map(add_values, data)) does not work
    dfs = pool.map(add_values, data)

print(type(dfs))
# Reducing return values
for d in dfs:
    df = df.add(d)

print(df)
```

The reduction must happen in a single process, as the different processes do not share the same `df` (instead they all have identical copies).

As a side note, I think you should also consider using `multithreading` rahter than `multiprocessing`. It may be simpler as threads can share the same memory and reduce the need for copying memory. Also, since `pandas` reduces the GIL, there is not the problem of only one thread being able to execute at a time.